# Installing printer driver for Epson TM-T20ii on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: printing, epson

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on a machine as a POS. Once the Epson TM-T20ii  printer is loaded, it comes up with the following error:

```
CUPS server error
```

The CUPS error_log shows this error: `client-error-document-format-not-supported...`

Answer (score 4):

I see that Epson supplies a [driver called "TM-Intelligent Printer"](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=soft&scat=32) that seems to cover all the bases. It comes down as `tmx-cups-2.0.3.0.tar.gz` so if you *save* it to your Downloads folder.

Copy each line of command below; paste into a terminal; hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key after each paste; move to the next line. The commands to install:

```
cd Downloads
tar -zxvf tmx-cups-2.0.3.0.tar.gz
cd tmx-cups
sudo ./install.sh
```

If you delete what you have in your *Printers* folder for the TM before you start the above as you say the existing icon does not work. We hope the above does. *Copy* the above commands and paste them into a terminal.

Comment: Hey guys, do you have an experience of using this printer under Ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04? Does it work well? Do you have any issues?

Comment: It worked for me (partially, as it chopped off the upper side of the ticket) with an 80mm printer in ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Working perfectly on Ubuntu 18.04, make sure you have CUPS version 2.2.8 see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032847/unauthorized-error-when-adding-printers-through-cups-using-google-chrome-in-ub

Answer (score 0):

My feedback. It works under LinuxMint 19 (Ubuntu 18.04), CUPS version 2.2.7.

1. When I first added the printer with the system tool, it suggested to select the "Generic" driver. I validated this choice, and it was probably a wrong one.

I couldn't print a test page from the CUPS interface (http://localhost:631/), I got:

```
    Unsupported format "application/vnd.cups-pdf-banner".
```

2. I installed the "TM-intelligent printer" driver linked in the other answer. The test page didn't work either.
3. I removed the printer from my system and re-added it, this time **selecting the `Epson / TM-BA Series Thermal` driver**. Probably the one linked in the other answer.

It works o/

I confirm it chops off the half of the first line.

I have CUPS 2.2.7, didn't have to upgrade.