# Install Epson TM-T88V drivers on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

I am relatively new to Ubuntu and tearing my hair out trying to get the drivers installed for thermal printer Epson TM-T88V on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

So far I have download the drivers from [this page](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=5012&scat=32&pcat=52)

I have then run the scripts I found here: [Installing printer driver for Epson TM-T20ii on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026572/installing-printer-driver-for-epson-tm-t20ii-on-ubuntu-16-04)

```
cd Downloads
tar -zxvf tmx-cups-2.0.3.0.tar.gz
cd tmx-cups
sudo ./install.sh
```

I also unpacked the file tm-ba-thermal-rastertotmt.ppd in the download folder.

I then used the printer settings to add the printer and load the tm-ba-thermal-rastertotmt.ppd from the download location.  The printer appears to be set up and shows as ready but will not print.

Can anyone assist with this please?  As a newbie I would appreciate a step by step. Thanks

Comment: Hey did you find a solution? Where you able to print?

Answer (score 1):

Below are scripts to install Epson TM-T88V and a Munbyn Printer that we also use in our business

Download or copy Epson Linux Driver to download folder
Go to the download folder, and find tm-ba-thermal-rastertotmt.ppd.gz - extract the file to the same folder
This file is called tm-ba-thermal-rastertotmt.ppd

cd Downloads
tar -zxvf tmx-cups-2.0.3.0.tar.gz
cd tmx-cups
sudo ./install.sh

Ensure the printer is attached via USB cable and switched on
Go to Settings/Devices/Printers
Use ADDITIONAL PRINTER SETTINGS - DO NOT USE GREEN ADD PRINTER BUTTON!!
Then use ADD Green Arrow
The printer should appear as Epson-TM-BA-Thermal
Click on this
Then use the dialogue to provide PPD file
Navigate to the download folder, then to the directory where tm-ba-thermal-rastertotmt.ppd is located and use this file as the PPD
Change settings to Thermal paper, open cash drawer before printing

Below for Munbyn thermal printer

Download or Copy POS-80 Driver from MunByn

Open Terminal in POS-80 Folder
Log in as Super User - su  then administrator password
If Super User is not enabled follow this script

To enable root account in Ubuntu, run the following command:

sudo passwd root
Copy
You will be prompted to enter and confirm the new root password:

Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully

From Super user login on terminal type

chmod 777  POS-80

CD POS-80

Enter

Then type

./POS-80

Enter

This installs the POS-80 Driver into the CUPS Printer service
http://localhost:631/admin

ADD PRINTER

CUPS will ask for user name and password which is the master administrator password

Ensure the Printer is connected via USB cable and and switched on

Printer will appear as unknow printer
Click continue
Complete Printer name as required
Driver will be in the LIST as POS

Once added set thermal paper, open cash draw and partial cut to complete set up

Comment: Epson t88v installation works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes the drivers have to be installed via cups service, Ubuntu 19.04 did not recognise this printer as a pl

Comment: Could you develop somewhat this answer?  How do you 'install drivers via cups service'?